# Clicks not being registered in new Kubuntu 16.10 install

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I am having some trouble getting my Kubuntu install up and running. I have installed Kubuntu 16.10 (dual booting with Windows 10).

It boots successfully and I am able to type in my password and log in, but when I get to the desktop I cannot click on anything, but I can move my mouse around. My keyboard is also unresponsive except for the number keys at the top of the keyboard. For some reason when I restart the X Window Server (using sudo sysctl service sddm.service restart) I am able to use the desktop correctly (my mouse and keyboard both work).

I have enabled legacy USB options in my BIOS and I am also booting using BIOS booting. I also had the same problem while installing Kubuntu (where I had to restart the X Window Server) and I also had the same server during and after installation of Kubuntu 16.04.1

I am running a Asus P8-Z77-V LX motherboard with an i5 and 16GB of RAM. The mouse I am currently using is a R.A.T. 7 but I have also tried with a generic mouse and the problem persists. The keyboard and mouse both use USB and the keyboard also has a USB hub (one usb port).

The mouse is plugged into the usb port on the keyboard, but as I stated, I have also tried a generic usb mouse and it was plugged into a different port.

The odd thing is that I can move the mouse around but whenever I hover over something (like the "start button" at the bottom left) the hover effect doesn't show and I can't click on the button. But then when I restart the X Server the hover effect shows again and I can once again click on the buttons.

Since I run Windows as well, I am relatively sure that the keyboard and mouse (and their ports) work correctly.